# Align Hash command in Textmate

Tags: textmate

There is an "Align Assignments" command in Textmate. I wonder if there is a similar command that can align Ruby/JavaScript hashes?

So I need to convert:

```
hash = {
  aaa: 123,
  bbbbbbbbb: 123,
  c: 123
}
```

to

```
hash = {
  aaa:       123,
  bbbbbbbbb: 123,
  c:         123
}
```

Or maybe there is some clever way to use Textmate column editing to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, TextMate does have this, but it only works for regular hash syntax (hash rockets =>), not compact hash syntax (symbol: value).

I don't know what it's called, but the keystroke `cmd-shift-]` (close square bracket), while the cursor is in a hash will turn this:

```
{
  :a => 1,
  :aaa => 2
  :b => 3
}
```

into this:

```
{
  :a   => 1,
  :aaa => 2
  :b   => 3
}
```